# JSON at PostgreSQL 9.3+, it is so ugly?

Tags: json, postgresql

There are kind of "less ugly" option to get strings as `text`s and integers as `int`s?

All **leaves of a JSON-tree have well known datatypes**, so, how to say to  PostgreSQL to see the datatypes?

---

Examples of problems and UGLY solutions... There are less ugly solution?

```
SELECT version(); -- PostgreSQL 9.3

CREATE TABLE example (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  info JSON 
);
INSERT INTO example (info) VALUES
  ('{"aa":10,"bb":"nonono nononon"}'),
  ('{"aa":10,"x":"etc"}'),  
  ('{"aa":9,"x":"etc etc"}');

-- SIX ERROS... But human-readable syntax
SELECT DISTINCT info->'aa' FROM example;    -- ex.1
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY info->'aa';  -- ex.2
SELECT info->'x' FROM example WHERE info->'x' IS NOT NULL; -- ex.3
SELECT * FROM example WHERE info->'x'='etc';  -- ex.4
SELECT * FROM example WHERE (info->'x')::text='etc';  -- ex.5
SELECT * FROM example WHERE info->'aa'=10;  -- ex.6

-- UGLY (!!) six workarounds
SELECT DISTINCT (info->'aa')::text FROM example;        -- ex.1
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY (info->'aa')::text::int; -- ex.2
SELECT info->'x' FROM example WHERE (info->'x')::text IS NOT NULL; -- ex.3
SELECT * FROM example WHERE trim((info->'x')::text,'"')='etc';  -- exs. 4 and 5
SELECT * FROM example WHERE (info->'aa')::text::int=10;  -- ex.6
```

Comment: `jsonb` in 9.4 provides some better facilities too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `->>` [json operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), which returns a JSON object fields or a JSON array as `text`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT info->>'aa' FROM example;
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY info->>'aa';
SELECT info->>'x' FROM example WHERE (info->>'x') IS NOT NULL;
SELECT * FROM example WHERE info->>'x'='etc';
SELECT * FROM example WHERE (info->>'aa')::int=10;  -- still needs a cast to int
```

Comment: Thanks! *ex.2* also still needs a cast to int :-)    `ORDER BY (info->>'aa')::int`