# How to cast a JSON value to its correspondent datatype?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

JSON-string is SQL-text, JSON-number is SQL-numeric, JSON-boolean is SQL-boolean... So I can do "real good cast"... But:

```
SELECT to_jsonb('hello'::text)::text
```

is not good. Returning with quotes.  Worst case:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(1::int)::int;
-- ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to integer
```

So, how to do casting?

Answer (score 1):

((this is a Wiki, you can edit!))

### (update for) Modern PostgreSQL do direct cast!

Example using pg 13.5:

```sql
SELECT (('{"x":123}'::jsonb)->'x')::int; -- ok no error!
SELECT (('{"x":123.44}'::jsonb)->'x')::float; -- ok no error!
SELECT (('{"x":123.44}'::jsonb)->'x')::numeric; -- ok no error!
SELECT (('{"x":"hello !"}'::jsonb)->'x')::text; -- no error, but quotes
SELECT ('{"x":"hello !"}'::jsonb)->>'x'; -- ok!

-- Modern versions not need cast for simple operations:

SELECT (('{"x":123}'::jsonb)->'x')::int + 3;     -- Ok, but...
SELECT jsonb_path_query('{"x":123}', '$.x + 3'); -- How about this!
```

---

### OLD answers for pg 9.4

#### Ugly ways only...

Today PostgreSQL is not so serious about JSON... So, let's workaround.

Sorry there are questions ([mine!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33986980/287948)) and answers. The answer with the [most simple solution is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757242/287948):

> In pg v9.4.4+ using the [`#>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) operator works for me: `select to_json('test'::text)#>>'{}';`

So, using the question's example:

```
SELECT (to_json(1::int)#>>'{}')::int;  -- the cast works
```

---

#### JSONb question... Internal binary value was reused?

```
SELECT (to_jsonB(10.7::numeric)#>>'{}')::numeric; -- internal repres. preserved? 
SELECT (to_jsonB(10.7::float)#>>'{}')::float; -- internal repres. preserved? 
 -- internal JSONb was float or numeric?
SELECT (to_jsonB(true)#>>'{}')::boolean;  -- internal representation preserved?
```

... there are **no guarantee** that PostgreSQL's internal parser is doing the correct thing, **reusing internal numerical representation** of JSONb to avoid CPU-time consuption (converting jsonb-number to SQL-text,  them casting text to SQL-number).

"JSONb cast optimization" or "SQL datatypes/JSONb datatypes convertion optionmization" seems to still be a big gap for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution that I've found for PostgreSQL.

Assuming:

```
{
"additionaldata" :
   {
      "Duration" : "123.44"
   }
}
```

The following select works:

```
select
  (additionaldata -> 'Duration')::jsonb::text::numeric as durationSeconds
from ...
```

Comment: Hi Mike, this is a very old question, now I am using PostgreSQL version 13.5 and it casts direct. Using your example for a numeric JSON datatype (not string as you tested), `SELECT (j->'Duration')::float FROM (SELECT ('{"additionaldata":{"Duration":123.44}}'::jsonb)->'additionaldata') t(j);`  the result is fine, a float.

Comment: That appears to work because the "Duration":123.44 creates a numeric in the jsonb, so you can cast it directly. I couldn't quickly figure out how to create a "Duration":"123.44" using that FROM syntax in pgAdmin.

The syntax I presented above does work when querying my data.  Trying to go directly to numeric yields an error:
ERROR:  cannot cast type json to numeric
LINE 5:   (additionaldata -> 'Duration')::numeric as durationSeconds...

Comment: Yes, you "cannot cast type json", this question is about jsonB... Sorry the old text in the questions's title and introduction not say explicitally, but the examples show that is jsonB

Comment: I see what you're saying.  In my case the jsonb contained a number represented as a string.  I needed it represented as a number, thus my solution.  It does answer a slightly different question, so maybe not appropriate.  However, it's what I found when searching for casting questions.  Hopefully it will help someone.